# cellarray of matrix multiplication vectorization

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have `A` and `B` a cell array of matrices inside. I want to obtain `C`

```
A = 
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]

B = 
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]
    [18x18 double]

K = magic(18);
```

In for loop:

```
C = cell(8,1);
for ii = 1:8
    C{ii} = K*A{ii}'*B{ii};
end
```

How can I do this in a vectorized form (cell)?

Comment: I don't see how you could vectorize without converting the cell arrays to multidimensiional arrays

Comment: @Luis Mendo  i mean i want to convert back to cell array at the end of the results C. In the middle of the process I can use multidimensiional arrays. But I still want to use cell to store all the matrices at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's possible,

```
K = repmat({K}, 8,1);
C = spblkdiag(K{:}) * spblkdiag(A{:}).' * spblkdiag(B{:});
C = reshape(nonzeros(C), 18,[]);
C = mat2cell(C, 18,18 * ones(8,1))';
```

I'd still suggest you use a loop.